# How to create instance of a django model

Tags: python, html, django, web-development-server, web-developer-toolbar

`views.py`

```
def create_post(request):
    profile_inst = Profile.objects.filter(author_real=request.user).first()

    print(profile_inst)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('POST request')
        form = CreatePost(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.FILES)
            form.save()
        
    else:
        print('JUST a VISIT!')
        form=CreatePost(initial={'author':profile_inst})
    
    return render(request,'create_post.html',{'form':form})
```

```
ValueError at /create_post/
Cannot assign "'username | admin'": "Post.author" must be a "Profile" instance.
```

`Post Model`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,default="No Title")
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',default='')
    content = RichTextField(default='',blank=True,null=True)


     def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
```

`CreatePost Model`

```
class CreatePost(ModelForm):
    thumbnail = forms.ImageField()
    title = forms.TextInput()
    author = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    # author = forms.TextInput(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model=Post
        exclude=['views','posted_on','post_id']
```

above is my view to create post on the blog i'm making, but for some reason django is not accepting profile_inst as a Profile instance and givin' the error shown above.

Please ignore the post_id field, that i just created for some purpose but is not yet being used yet as of my knowledge.

appreciating any efforts!

Comment: Please share the `CreatePost` form and the `Post` model.

Comment: does "POST request" get printed or "JUST a VISIT!"?

Comment: if there's a POST request, then 'POST REQUEST' is being printed else 'JUST a VISIT!'.

Comment: I added more fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the below code with `commit=False`.

```
form = CreatePost(request.POST,request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    print(request.FILES)
    post=form.save(commit=False)
    post.author = profile_inst
    post.save()
```

2. 

Since it is the logged-in use who creat posts, you don't need to let the user type their name. So remove `author = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())` line.
We can set post author automatically using 1) code.

```
class CreatePost(ModelForm):
    thumbnail = forms.ImageField()
    title = forms.TextInput()
# Remove the below lines
    #author = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    # author = forms.TextInput(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model=Post
        exclude=['views','posted_on','post_id']
```

3. 

If you want to show the user name/info in post creation form, use

`{{ request.user.profile }}`
.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: It worked man! Thanks for helping, was stuck with this for a quite lot time.

Comment: You can mark the answer as an accepted friend.

Comment: Yup,a newbie to stackoverflow, so didn't knew this, btw can i ask you how can we add two automatically generated fields in a django model, like here i'm struggling to add the post id after after adding the datetimefield.

Comment: Use same as above ``` post.post_id = 100  post.author = profile_inst
    post.save()```  .

Comment: But for your info > post already have automatically generated id field(hidden). You can access it like ```post_object.id``` . In template like `{{ post_object.id }}` .

Comment: Is this the case with every model we create?

Comment: Normally in Django yes. But if you want you can disable it and create your own automatic ID fields.(like uuid , int , string). But the main thing is ids must be unique for every object of a model. So It's better to let the Django do it.

Comment: Hmmm, Thanks for info man!Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not accepting profile_inst because you're not passing the instance to the form when the request is POST request, instead you're passing object of request.POST which contains a key  'username | admin' hence django ORM cannot match the above key to your post model field 'author'

Try creating object to pass to your form like this :

```
form_obj = {
   author : profile_inst, 
   ... other necessary form fields
}

form = CreatePost(form_obj, request.FILES)

... other code
```

Or change the name of input field from 'username | admin' to 'author' but you will need to check if the author exists and get its instance in createpost form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. But this still goes on with the same error.